# How do I detect "Easter Egg" mode in my Palm OS application?

Tags: c, palm-os, garnet-os

Since the early days, Palm OS has had a special "easter egg" mode that's enabled by making the right gesture in one of the Preference panels.  On current Palm Treo and Centro devices, this is turned on by doing a clockwise swirl above the "Tips" button in the Power panel.

Some applications, like the Blazer web browser, enable special features when easter eggs are active.  How can I detect this in my own program?

Comment: I used to do a lot of PalmOS dev about 6 years ago and your blog and posts on the PalmOS Usenet groups were a HUGE help.  Glad to see you're still at it.

Comment: Did you just ask that question so you could post an answer to it? it seems that you answered it the same minute you asked it...

Comment: You are allowed to do that, it says in the FAQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard system preference for this is prefAllowEasterEggs (see Preference.h). This setting can be accessed using the PrefGetPreference API:

```
UInt32 enableEasterEggs = PrefGetPreference(prefAllowEasterEggs);
```

The value will be non-zero when the user has requested that Easter eggs be available.